# Ошибка при миграции OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Привет. Перенёс свой свйт OpenCar с shared-хостинга на VPS, изменил конфиг. Сайт запустился, но сверху 4 варнинга:

```
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/system/cache/cache.country.status.1499866013): Permission denied in /var/www/html/system/library/cache/file.php on line 17
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/system/cache/cache.currency.1499864515): Permission denied in /var/www/html/system/library/cache/file.php on line 17
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/system/cache/cache.language.1499864515): Permission denied in /var/www/html/system/library/cache/file.php on line 17
Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/system/cache/cache.product.bestseller.1.0.1.1.1499864104): Permission denied in /var/www/html/system/library/cache/file.php on line 17
```

Ставил права 777 на `file.php`, и на файлы в папке cache. Я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: А вы уверены что поставили права на саму папку cache?

Comment: @emre не там стандартные 755.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin system/cache руками почистите. Только забекаптесь.